# "import flask" is working but "from flask import flask" is not?

Tags: python, flask, import

When I type into python `"import flask"` flask is imported with no problems.

But `"from flask import flask"` it says

`ImportError: cannot import name 'flask' from 'flask'.`

Most tutorials use `"from flask import flask"`, so should I be worried?

Comment: Did you mean `from flask import Flask`, with a capital letter on the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will be

```
from flask import Flask
```